# Spring typequery finders with order by clause

Tags: spring-mvc, hql

Using Spring MVC 3.0 and roo, i'm tryin to write a custom typequery finder with an order by clause.

This is what I've done thus far;

```
 public static TypedQuery<tt.edu.sbcs.model.SessionInfo> findAllSessionInfosByScheduleOrderByDisplayOrder(Schedule schedule) {
    if (schedule == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The schedule argument is required");
    EntityManager si = SessionInfo.entityManager();
    TypedQuery<SessionInfo> q = si.createQuery("SELECT o FROM SessionInfo As o WHERE o.schedule = :schedule ORDER BY o.displayOrder ASC", SessionInfo.class);
    q.setParameter("schedule", schedule);
    return q;
}
```

I'm not to sure if my query is wrong but for this query is returning an error. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is wrong:

```
"SELECT o FROM SessionInfo As o WHERE o.schedule = :schedule ORDER BY o.displayOrder ASC"
       ===
```

You are selecting the same column name as the Table alias.
You either need a list of columns or * for all columns